# not able to use tf.metrics.recall

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am very new to tensorflow.
I am just trying to understand how to use tf.metrics.recall

I am doing the following

```
true = tf.zeros([64, 1])
pred = tf.random_uniform([64,1], -1.0,1.0)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    t,p = sess.run([true,pred])
#     print(t)
#     print(p)
    rec, rec_op = tf.metrics.recall(labels=t, predictions=p)
    sess.run(rec_op,feed_dict={t: t,p: p})
    print(recall)
```

And that is giving me the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-7245c92d724d> in <module>
     25 #     print(p)
     26     rec, rec_op = tf.metrics.recall(labels=t, predictions=p)
---> 27     sess.run(rec_op,feed_dict={t: t,p: p})
     28     print(recall)

TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Please help me to understand this better.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

labels and predictions in your code return tensor outputs, which are numpy array. You can you numpy or your own implementation to calculate recall over them, if you wish. The benefit of using metrics is that you can run everything uniformly in one go with just tensorflow.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    rec, rec_op = tf.metrics.recall(labels=true, predictions=pred)
    batch_recall, _ = sess.run([rec, rec_op],feed_dict={t: t,p: p})
    print(recall)
```

Note, that you use tensors constructing tf.metrics.recall.